# iSorting a multi-dimensional array based off an array value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array which is loaded based of the results of a database query

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {   
            $response->rows[$i]['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
            # Row Data 
            $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array(
                                    $row['user_id'],
                                    $row['aff_code'],
                                    $row['lname'],
                                    $row['fname'],
                                    $new_comm,
                                    $mth_earn,
                                    $status_label);
           $i++;
        }
```

How can I sort this array by $new_comm, (numeric value)?

$new_comm and $mth_earn are calculated from a second call to the database.

Thank you

Comment: There are about a thousand different questions about this. Use the search and look at the "related" section on the right.

Comment: i would suggest sorting it within you sql query, so when you output to php - it's already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [usort()](http://www.php.net/usort%28%29)

the following requires php 5.3, otherwise replace the annonymous function with one made via [create_function()](http://www.php.net/create_function%28%29)

```
usort($response->rows, function($a, $b){
    return $b['cell'][4] - $a['cell'][4];
});
```

or with a cleverly implemented sort order option

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    $sortDescending = false;
    return (1 - 2*$sortDescending) * ($b['cell'][4] - $a['cell'][4]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.  That answered my question and got me close to my final solution.  I just need to add the option to reverse the sort order, which I assume would be by replacing the - with a +

Comment: To flip the sort order it would be return $a['cell'][4] - $b['cell'][4];

Comment: OK got the answer.  Needed to figure out how usort worked to understand what was going on.

usort($response->rows, function($a, $b){ 
  //return ($a['cell'][4] > $b['cell'][4]) ? 1 : -1;  // Ascending
  //return ($a['cell'][4] < $b['cell'][4]) ? 1 : -1;  // Descending
   
});